# Is it possible to disable source maps in Firefox (version 45.0.1)?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug, source-maps

There is the "Show Original Sources" checkbox but it seem not working. I tried to find a way to disable source maps in FF Developer Tools and Firebug but without any success.

[image: Screenshot]

BTW: It's easy to disable them in Chrome Dev Tools.

Comment: Not sure why you would want to disable source maps. Are you talking about only your browser, or all browsers running your code?

Comment: Only my browser. I need to disable them and debug original code.

Comment: You should add the version of Firefox you're using. Maybe it's a bug related to a specific release. Also, it would be helpful if you added an example page using source maps, so people can reproduce the issue.

Comment: I'm using Firefox 45.0.1 (the latest version at the moment).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was running into this issue as well until I realized that "Show Original Sources" in Firefox actually means "Use Source Maps," so you need to uncheck Show Original Sources in order to see the raw JS without Source Maps.

Source:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/Settings

Comment: This is called `Enable Source Maps` in 68.4.1esr.

Comment: Just `Source Maps` now (89). Hold over it will show the tool tip explains that this option let Firefox downloads the source file. Uncheck this and refresh the page.